# SOA: Biztalk ESB candidates for .Net

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture, soa, esb

Letting BizTalk aside - I like it, but only for variety purposes.

Which others ESB solutions would you use in a SOA .Net arquitecture?

thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 3):

We are using nServiceBus in a SOA system so far the results have been good. The biggest hurdle was understanding what SOA means. We followed Udi Dahan's definition and guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

[MassTransit](http://readthedocs.org/docs/masstransit/en/latest/) with [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) works for me.